# How to create a dynamically updating custom list view in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-listview

I want to show some text and an image in each listview element in my Listview. But the text and the image are actually stored in a MySQL database in my server.

I've figured out how to download the text and image pair from the MySQL database on the server. Can we create an dynamically updating ArrayList which is fed to a CustomListAdapter? Or is there any other way to show the ListView items similar to a Facebook News Feed?

Note: The image and text for each listview element would be downloaded in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Create model class With Bitmap and String and create an ArrayList of type Your model class .  Now retrieve data and set model class with bitmap and string and put this object into arraylist and fed this areaylist to your custom adapter . Will work . Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After change in your ArrayLists, you need to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to see the changes in the ArrayLists reflected in ListView.

Now download, update the ArrayLists supplied to adapter and call the above method whenever you want in the app based on how your functionality is expecting the ListView to refresh.